# change code generated HTML markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, xhtml

The following code:

```
    public virtual string LookupFeatureImages(string ProductID)
    {
        string[] features;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DB.GetDBConn()))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = @"SELECT     ExtensionData5
            FROM         Product
            WHERE     (ProductID = @ProductID)";
            using (IDataReader dr = DB.GetRS(query, new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@ProductID", ProductID) }, con))
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["ExtensionData5"].ToString()))
                    {
                        return "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        features = dr["ExtensionData5"].ToString().Split(',');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
       string s = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"skins/Skin_1/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"skins/Skin_1/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js\"></script><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"skins/Skin_1/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css\" media=\"screen\" />";
       s += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(function() {    $(\"a.iconClick\").fancybox({'hideOnContentClick': true, 'autoDimensions' : false, 'width' : 400, 'height' : 300 }); });</script>";

        s += "<table><tr>";
        for (int i = 0; i <= features.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            string name = features[i].Split(':')[0];
            bool isChecked = Boolean.Parse(features[i].Split(':')[2]);

            if (isChecked)
            {
                //s += "<td><img src=\"skins/skin_1/images/" + name + ".gif\" alt=\"" + name + "\" title=\"" + name + "\"></td>";
                s += "<td>";
                s += "<a class=\"iconClick\" rel=\"icons\" href='popup.aspx?title=" + name + "&topic=feature_" + name + "' title='" + name + "'><img src=\"skins/skin_1/images/" + name + ".gif\" alt=\"" + name + "\" title=\"" + name + "\"></a>";
                s += "</td>";

            }
        }
        s += "</tr><tr>";
        for (int i = 0; i <= features.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            string specification = features[i].Split(':')[1];
            bool isChecked = Boolean.Parse(features[i].Split(':')[2]);

            if (isChecked)
            {
                s += "<td>" + specification + "</td>";
            }
        }
        return s + "</tr></table>";
    }
```

Outputs HTML like this:

```
<table id="FeatureBox">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="productInfoGrid">
<p id="ProductIconsTitle">Product Features At-A-Glance (<a href=
"JavaScript:newPopup('t-featureicons.aspx');">key</a>)</p>
<script src=
"skins/Skin_1/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js"
type="text/javascript">
</script><script src=
"skins/Skin_1/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"
type="text/javascript">
</script><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {       $("a.iconClick").fancybox({'hideOnContentClick': true, 'autoDimensions' : false, 'width' : 400, 'height' : 300 }); });
</script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a title="classification" href=
"popup.aspx?title=classification&amp;topic=feature_classification"
rel="icons" class="iconClick"><img title="classification" alt=
"classification" src=
"skins/skin_1/images/classification.gif"></a></td>
<td><a title="maxcapacityadults" href=
"popup.aspx?title=maxcapacityadults&amp;topic=feature_maxcapacityadults"
rel="icons" class="iconClick"><img title="maxcapacityadults" alt=
"maxcapacityadults" src=
"skins/skin_1/images/maxcapacityadults.gif"></a></td>
<td><a title="maxcapacitychildren" href=
"popup.aspx?title=maxcapacitychildren&amp;topic=feature_maxcapacitychildren"
rel="icons" class="iconClick"><img title="maxcapacitychildren" alt=
"maxcapacitychildren" src=
"skins/skin_1/images/maxcapacitychildren.gif"></a></td>
<td><a title="maxloadcapacity" href=
"popup.aspx?title=maxloadcapacity&amp;topic=feature_maxloadcapacity"
rel="icons" class="iconClick"><img title="maxloadcapacity" alt=
"maxloadcapacity" src=
"skins/skin_1/images/maxloadcapacity.gif"></a></td>
<td><a title="numberofinflatablechambers" href=
"popup.aspx?title=numberofinflatablechambers&amp;topic=feature_numberofinflatablechambers"
rel="icons" class="iconClick"><img title=
"numberofinflatablechambers" alt="numberofinflatablechambers" src=
"skins/skin_1/images/numberofinflatablechambers.gif"></a></td>
<td><a title="packagingsize" href=
"popup.aspx?title=packagingsize&amp;topic=feature_packagingsize"
rel="icons" class="iconClick"><img title="packagingsize" alt=
"packagingsize" src=
"skins/skin_1/images/packagingsize.gif"></a></td>
<td><a title="sizeinflated" href=
"popup.aspx?title=sizeinflated&amp;topic=feature_sizeinflated" rel=
"icons" class="iconClick"><img title="sizeinflated" alt=
"sizeinflated" src="skins/skin_1/images/sizeinflated.gif"></a></td>
<td><a title="standard" href=
"popup.aspx?title=standard&amp;topic=feature_standard" rel="icons"
class="iconClick"><img title="standard" alt="standard" src=
"skins/skin_1/images/standard.gif"></a></td>
<td><a title="weight" href=
"popup.aspx?title=weight&amp;topic=feature_weight" rel="icons"
class="iconClick"><img title="weight" alt="weight" src=
"skins/skin_1/images/weight.gif"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="featureNames">
<td>III,B</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>130 kg</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>79 x 28 x 51 cm</td>
<td>305 x 84 cm</td>
<td>ISO 6185-1</td>
<td>10.6 kg</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="c1"></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I change the output to DIVs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure as to what you are asking. If you want your code to be displayed in div instead of table, tr and td, that can be easily achieved from within the code. Simply remove the table and tr tags from the output and replace all td tags with div tags. That should effectively remove any table formatting and change everything to div.

Comment: How do i add a div class or table class to the code? is its a string builder right?

Comment: A stringbuilder is not very different from a string. A stringbuilder has the property of being modifiable. So whenever you append to a string, you actually create a new string. Inspite of the obvious advantage of the stringbuilders, working with strings is more intuitive and should be changed at a later stage when you are optimizing your code. As for the given code snippet, remove `s+="<table><tr>"`, then remove s+=`</tr><tr>`, then change the return statement to `return s` instead of `return s+"</tr></table>"`. Finally, change `s+="<td>"` to 's+="<div>"` and `s+="<\td>"` to `s+="<\div>"`

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery change your output. For example, you can get $("#FeatureBox") table(or what ever you need), after that, use css or html methods